# Some malware in PdfCreator forces now my Chrome to Bing

Tags: malware, pdfcreator

How do I get rid of it? I already put Google back as default search engine in settings, completely deleted Bing from that list, and even removed Chrome and reinstalled it - it still refers to Bing.

I can't understand why PdfCreator is recommended despite the amount of malware that's in there.

[image: Google as default]

Comment: Its likely because the "malware" is easily avoided by selecting NOT to install it.  If you have already reversed the damage what exactly is your question?

Comment: I haven't reverted the damage. Despite Chrome being selected I still end up with being redirected to Bing. (I've updated the question now)

Comment: And yes. If a tool takes actually effort to destroy  the 'Settings' functionality within Chrome I think it deserves the word Malware - without any quotes.

Comment: What you describe actually is adware not malware.

Answer (score 1):

There were apparently two Malwares installed when installing PdfCreator, one of them being [BingProtect from a company called BBI](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/bing-protect-removal/)

As the default uninstaller didn't work for me, I used a tool called AdwCleaner - that worked for me in the end.